# Where to place a cooling fan supply capacitor

Tags: emc, fan, electrolytic-capacitor

I want to run a ~2W, 12 VDC fan in an EMI-sensitive environment.

The schematic is shown below. Due to the spiky current draw, I intend to place C1 and C2 right by the fan connector, so high frequency current draw across the board's power distribution network is reduced. I don't want large currents in the frequency band from about 1 kHz to 1 MHz drawn across the board because it could interfere with sensitive analog circuitry, and obviously I want to contain >10 MHz currents very locally due to EMI.

When transistor M1 is suddenly and fully turned-off while the fan is still spinning, a back emf current will flow through D1, taking the fan 'out' node and C1 voltage to about -0.7 V.

C1 is a polarized Al electrolytic with 0.5..1.5 Ohm ESR. Is this reverse voltage across C1 a problem for it? That situation can occur multiple times per day.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fchmXz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have studied capacitor datasheets of several Al electrolytic capacitors that could fit the role of C1 from several reputable manufacturers. In datasheets of parts from  Nichicon, Rubycon, Cornell, United Chemicon, I could not find any discussion of reverse voltage situations. [A Panasonic datasheet](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDE0000/ABA0000C1175.pdf) at least contained a very short hint under 1.3.(1), namely: *"[...], do not apply the reverse voltage. Find the correct polarity before insertion."*. I am not able to draw any informed conclusion based on these datasheets. If such a situation would always lead to permanent damage, wouldn't all the manufacturers feel obliged to add a bold hint in their datasheets ?

Comment: You haven't spec'd what type of capacitor C1 is. If it's a ceramic, for example, then there's no problem.

Comment: Change D1 to Schottky?

Comment: You need to check the datasheet for the capacitor but lower negative voltage should be lower stress overall. If the datasheet limit is 0.5 V than you move from over stress to within limit.

Comment: @winny Is there some important threshold that makes -0.4 V much safer than -0.7 V? I have added more information found in several datasheets. It wasn't of much use tbh.

Comment: You have a bigger problem, your 100µF capacitor is surging through your mosfet at turnon. You don't really need it anyway

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio why would you suggest removing C1 ? won't that cause current spikes to be drawn all the way from the 12V PSU ? Or do you suggest to move the cap to the left side of MOSFET (on the 12V rail) ? There are capacitors on the 12 V rail anyway, but they are further away.

Comment: On maybe removing C1: there's no details of the frequencies you're trying to remove. Often, much lower values like 10..100 nF are what you'd see across a small (fan) motor to reduce EMI. Were these 100 uF and 1 uF values chosen from any calculation or testing, or just by guesswork or 'well we used these values last time'? I wouldn't be surprised if, say, a 10 uF ceramic and a 100 nF across the fan did what you wanted. But there's no details of your application, environment etc. so no-one can say.

Comment: @TonyM I believe this came from some "guides" in the web, which I can't point to now, but the rationale was: An electrolytic cap of ~100µF to eat the motor current spikes (~1kHz to 1 MHz band) and a much smaller ceramic cap for EMI control. Having said that, a small drain-to-gate cap should also enable to draw spikes from the 12 V rail when the electrolytic cap is there. This topic here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247077/how-to-filter-noise-from-fan also arrived at the conclusion that no output electrolytic cap was needed..... added more info to OP.

Comment: @tobalt the drain-to-gate cap is called an active clamp and could actually of help. As for the electrolytic my doubt wasn't about the capacity but the technology: for a brushed motor I had to use 10µF to quench the brush noise but ceramic since electrolytics simply suck at high frequency

Answer (score -1):

This reverse voltage under 1 volt is not a problem for capacitors.
I already make a test on 16 V capacitor with one volt reverse and result is no current flow and the capasitor not affected.
Usually one and half volt is limit of capacitors.

Comment: Thank you. Could you detail a bit what "my experience" means ? Have you used capacitors in this manner for an extended period of time?

Comment: This is an opinion, not an answer with a definitive explanation. Downvoting until improved. Might be a new user innocently using 'Answer' on this Q&A site like 'Reply' is used on discussion forums, so could be deleted and reposted as a comment.

Comment: I see a lot of circuits use diode like this to protect capacitor and i already test it for you i put 1 volt in reverse across 16 volt capasitor for five minutes and nothing happen

Comment: Thank you for the test, Omar, I suggest you add this information to your answer.

Comment: That's still opinion, I'm afraid, and doesn't answer the question. A subjective test on one part for a few minutes doesn't remotely prove a part will work within specifications for its life across full temperature and humidity and at full voltage range. It just shows 1 part didn't have a catastrophic failure. Walking across a road with your eyes shut ten times doesn't prove roads are safe. Your answer should specify capacitor technology with reference to its datasheet. Good design is not designing something that works - that's relatively easy. It's designing something that never doesn't work.

Comment: *"Usually one and half volt is limit of capasitor"* Is this a reliable figure due to the involved chemistry or something ?

Comment: I see a lot of circuit use just a diode like this and it work perfectly if you know any notice or have experience with it tell us

Comment: Five minutes and nothing happened does not tell anything about long term usage. Many of capacitor manufacturers do not recommend polarized electrolytics to be used in a circuit where reverse polarity may occur.

Comment: Please write to your best ability. A spell checker would catch “capasitor” immediately. Sentences end with period, exclamation mark or question mark.